# First option hiding in SELECT works only for the first select, not for all

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I have an issue with some code.
Basically I want to remove the first option from `<select>` using jQuery, which is working, but only for the very first select. If I have 3 dropdowns the code works only for the first one. I tried to use `.each` but to be honest I don't really know where and will this even help.
This is a html:

```
      <select class="checkb" name="gender">
     <option disabled value="">Gender</option>
     <option value="male">Male</option>
     <option value="female">Female</option>
  </select>  

  <select class="checkb" name="age">
     <option disabled value="">Age</option>
     <option value="under 13">Under 13</option>
     <option value="13-17">13-17</option>
     <option value="18-24">18-24</option>
     <option value="25-44">25-44</option>
     <option value="45-64">45-64</option>
     <option value="65+">65+</option>
  </select>  

  <select class="checkb" name="cinema">
     <option disabled value="">Select your cinema</option>
     <option value="001">Cinema 1</option>
     <option value="002">Cinema 2</option>
     <option value="003">Cinema 3</option>
  </select>
```

and this is jquery:

```
    $(".checkb option:first").attr('hidden','hidden');
```

It perfectly hides the 'Gender' text, but doesn't hide 'Age' and 'Select your cinema'.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That selector will select the first `<option>` element it finds that's within an element with the class `.checkb`, which is why it's only removing the first `<option>` from the first `<select>`.

You could instead use the [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector to get all `<option>` elements that are the first child of the `<select>` with that class:

```
$('.checkb option:nth-child(1)').attr('hidden', 'hidden');
```

Edit: I was curious about the efficiency of three approaches to solving this (the two suggested in the current answers, as well as a third that's a variation of Christopher Kenney's answer) so decided to test it. You can see the results [here](http://jsperf.com/nth-child-vs-each-first-vs-each-eq).

Comment: @Piotr: I just thought the same, but I wanted to check that to be sure, see for yourself at: http://jsfiddle.net/PKPwR/5/

Comment: This works great, the result is exactly as needed. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

well the `:first` tells jquery to only act upon the first child (and in this case of the first element of the class) so remove it and make your code like the following:

```
$('.checkb').each(function () {
  $(this).children('option:first').attr('hidden','hidden');
});
```